# When and why did competence become "competency"?

Tags: meaning

I don't remember ever hearing "competency" until circa 1970. When I first heard that form it sounded very silly, as if someone was trying to sound lofty via the addition of superfluous syllables.

Is there a context where "competency" is correct usage, and "competence" wouldn't do just as well?

Is it a recent (last 40 yrs) permutation, or is it my sheltered background that made it sound that way?

(Is anyone here old enough to know?)

Okay, that's *three* questions, sorry!

Comment: My answer would be that "competency" is to "competence" as "nonsency" is to "nonsense", the last of these four words being the pith of my answer!

Answer (score 10):

The 1831 edition of Noah Webster's dictionary defines *competence* and *competency* as synonyms:

> Sufficiency, legal capacity, or right,
>   fitness, adequacy.

[Google Ngrams](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=competence%2C+competency&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) shows them being used roughly equally often until 1920, when *competence* starts winning. So *competency* is not an obnoxious neologism, although it reached a low point around 1960, and may have been revived slightly since then.

I believe that in modern usage, they are no longer exact synonyms.

Although different people undoubtedly use the words in different ways, I would say that *competence* and *compentency* tend to be related the same way that *dependence* and *dependency* are.

A *dependency* is something which is *dependent* on something else. (Although in terms of territories, *puppet* may often be closer to its actual meaning.)

A *competency* is an area where you are *competent*.

Comment: I stand corrected, then.  Still hate the word, because I only hear it in an HR context, and that's a hard stink to wash off.

Comment: @MT_Head: I agree. *Competency* seems to be currently mainly used in education, business strategy, and HR contexts, all of which lend it some element of stink.

Answer (score 7):

Both words can be traced back to Shakespeare.

He used *competence* in *[Henry IV, Part 2](http://books.google.com/books?id=LJ0UAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA83&dq=%22competence%22&hl=en&ei=VS_sTZq3OsjUgQfmionZCQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CDsQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=competence&f=false)*, 1594:

[image: http://books.google.com/books?id=LJ0UAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA83&dq=%22competence%22&hl=en&ei=VS_sTZq3OsjUgQfmionZCQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CDsQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=competence&f=false]

And *competency* in *[The Merchant of Venice](http://books.google.com/books?id=RAcJAAAAQAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=merchant%20of%20venice&hl=en&ei=9jHsTZzELIXpgQeR1L3XCQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=competency&f=false)*, 1600:

[image: http://books.google.com/books?id=RAcJAAAAQAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=merchant+of+venice&hl=en&ei=9jHsTZzELIXpgQeR1L3XCQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=competency&f=false]

However, from [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=competency%20competence&searchmode=or), it looks like these words originally had different meanings than they do now:

> **competence**
>   1590s, "rivalry;" c.1600 "adequate supply;" 1630s, "sufficiency of means for living at ease," from Fr. *compétence*, from L. *competentia* "meeting together, agreement, symmetry," from *competens*, prp. of *competere* (see *compete*). Meaning "sufficiency to deal with what is at hand" is from 1790.

Answer (score 3):

In general, "competence" is used to describe one's general fitness or ability - "[Loughner's Mental Competence Is Doubted](http://online.wsj.com/article/SB10001424052748703509104576328100954614650.html)", *Wall Street Journal* headline - whereas "competency" (which, I agree, is an obnoxious neologism) means "fitness or ability to complete a certain task" - "[Educational Competency Assessment](http://www.aicpa-eca.org/)."

I believe the distinction arose out of human-resources law; if you question someone's (an employee's, a coworker's) competence, you come perilously close to making a value judgment about them as a human being (which can lead to lawsuits); if you say that they "lack competency", they may be trained (or not) but you aren't damning them out of hand.

Comment: @Safari7: If you feel one of these has sufficiently answered your question, you can choose it by clicking the check icon to the left of the question.

Answer (score 2):

I have been looking for clarification on the difference, as *competence* and *competency* appear to be used to mean the same thing in our company documents. The best (and simplest) definition I found is:

> Though both having similar meanings, *competence* and *competency* are used in different contexts.
>
> *Competence* refers to a person’s ability or skills and knowledge that he possesses.
>
> *Competencies* of a job refer to description of how things have to be done and at what level.

This comes from a very good article that can be found [here](http://www.differencebetween.com/difference-between-competence-and-vs-competency/#ixzz3ASQPb942).